# How to fill landscape page with four images

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, captions, landscape

I have huge set of weather related images with are plotted for 12 months for various cities. I would like to present these images to the users in the form of pdf in **landscape** layout in an organised manner. So that it would be easy for reference. The basic idea is to place four images with some caption as shown below:-
[image: Concept of the image lcations]
Basically A and C are interrelated and B and D are interrelated. Therefore, I would like to draw a box around it and place A&C and B&D side by side (top and bottom). The size of A & B is 747x559 pixels and C&D is 1044x1111 pixels.

I have seen some of the code in this forum and found some basic latex code to place the image like below:-

```
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=400px\linewidth,height=200px, left]{bar_at_April_7.png}
\includegraphics[width=400px\linewidth,height=200px, right]{bar_at_April_7.png}
\includegraphics[width=400px\linewidth,height=300px, left]{wr_at_April_7.png}
\includegraphics[width=400px\linewidth,height=300px, right]{wr_at_April_7.png}
\end{center}
\caption{ 4 figures}
```

However, I am not getting the expected result. Here is the basic output I got:-

[image]

It lines up all the images in the harizontal fashion and puts the last image in to next page.

So my query is that how do you put all these four images in the same manner I have listed in the first image? Some code sample would be of great help.

Comment: Will every image have its own caption, (figure 1, figure 2,...)  or will the have a common caption and every figure has its own subcaption ((a), (b), ...)?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the following is close to what you want to achieve:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
%\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=0.45\linewidth,frame=1pt 5pt}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\smallskip

\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\end{adjustbox}
\hfill
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=0.45\linewidth,frame=1pt 5pt}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\smallskip

\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{adjustbox}
\caption{This is the caption}
\end{figure}
%\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It does not work. It puts each image in four pages. For infor, I used pandoc to convert the tex to pdf using this command `pandoc input.tex -t latex -V geometry:landscape  -o output.pdf`